# Colour guessing game

Tags: javascript

I have been assigned to create a colour guessing game. The Idea is that the player needs to guess the colour and once they guess correctly the background will change. However, I am struggling to get the game up and running on my browser. I have looked in the console and don't understand the errors highlighted.

```js
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload = game()

var colours=["blue","purple","pink","red","green","yellow"];
// var target_index
var target
var guess_input
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;

  function game () {
    var random_colours = Math.floor(Math.random()* colours.length);
    target = random_colours;

    while (!finished) {
    guess_input = prompt ("I'm thinking of one of these colours\n" + colours + "\n What colour am I thinking of?")
    guesses += 1;
    finished = check_guess ();
    }
  }


  function check_guess () {
    if (guess_input == isNaN) {
      alert ("I don't recgonise\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }

    if (guess_input > target) {
      alert ("Your colour is alphabetically higher than mine\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }

    if (guess_input < target) {
      alert ("Your colour is alphabetically lower than mine\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }
    if (guess_input == target) {
      alert ("Congratulations, the colour was" + target + "it took you" + guesses + "to finish the game!" "You can see the color in the background");
      return true;
    }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of things wrong.
First, the snippet had an extra `<body><script type="text/javascript">`. Remove that.

Secondly, you are associating a function on `window.onload` before the variables are declared, this will cause `colour` variable to be undefined upon calling. Just move all your variables before `window.onload = game()`.

Mind that you will get stuck in a loop until you get the color right, but I'm purely fixing the error as the question poses.

Here is the working snippet, I **urge** not to run in here.

```js
var colours=["blue","purple","pink","red","green","yellow"];
// var target_index
var target
var guess_input
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;

 window.onload = game();


  function game () {
    var random_colours = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
    target = random_colours;

    while (!finished) {
  guess_input = prompt ("I'm thinking of one of these colours\n" + colours + "\n What colour am I thinking of?")
  guesses += 1;
  finished = check_guess();
    }
  }


  function check_guess () {
    if (guess_input == isNaN) {
      alert ("I don't recgonise\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }

    if (guess_input > target) {
      alert ("Your colour is alphabetically higher than mine\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }

    if (guess_input < target) {
      alert ("Your colour is alphabetically lower than mine\n" + "Please try again");
      return false;
    }
    if (guess_input == target) {
      alert ("Congratulations, the colour was" + target + "it took you" + guesses + "to finish the game!" + "You can see the color in the background");
      return true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```